# How do I assess goodness of fit when I don't have a model, only results of it?

Tags: survival, goodness-of-fit

I'm trying to assess goodness of fit for survival.

I am using output of a parametric model for survival. I have the the survival at each year from time 0 to time 70 months. This model was created using individual patient data but then modified manually by changing hazard risks for a component risk of death. I do have knowledge of how the manual adjustment was made and I can reproduce it.

So, to re-iterate, there is no statistical model that represents the output; I just have the survival at each time from 0 to 70 months.

I also have the individual patient data.

My objective is to assess how well the manually modified parametric model fits the observed data. How do I do this?